# Vuejs Component Not Rendering though registered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a dropdown component called "MissionPlanner" in a single page component .vue file and I registered it in my App.vue file

App.vue

```
import MissionPlanner from "./MissionPlanner.vue";

export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
      ...,
    "mission-planner": MissionPlanner
  }
...
<template>
   <mission-planner/>
</template
```

But when I tried to run the vue application, it is not showing my component at all. I do see the rest of my template html being rendered but not the dropdown component "mission-planner". I even tried changing the case for the "mission-planner" tag names to "MissionPlanner" but still nothing.

Also here is my main.js

```
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  components: {
    "mission-planner": require("./MissionPlanner.vue")
  } //tried registering it globally but it is not working
}).$mount('#app')
```

Update:
ok looking closer at the console, i see several errors but not sure what they mean:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "chosen" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <MissionPlanner> at src/MissionPlanner.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
warnNonPresent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2015
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2070
eval @ MissionPlanner.vue?93e1:18
renderList @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2630
render @ MissionPlanner.vue?93e1:16
Vue._render @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3548
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4468
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4073
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8415
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5978
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5925
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6053
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5954
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6477
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3945
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4468
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4073
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8415
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5978
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5925
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6516
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3945
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4468
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4073
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8415
eval @ main.js?56d7:8
./src/main.js @ app.js:1366
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:785
fn @ app.js:151
1 @ app.js:1379
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:785
checkDeferredModules @ app.js:46
(anonymous) @ app.js:861
(anonymous) @ app.js:864
Show 13 more frames
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '#<Object>' in NaN"

found in

---> <MissionPlanner> at src/MissionPlanner.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1884
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
Vue._render @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3550
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4468
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4073
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8415
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5978
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5925
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6053
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5954
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6477
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3945
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4468
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4073
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8415
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5978
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5925
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6516
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3945
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4468
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4073
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8415
eval @ main.js?56d7:8
./src/main.js @ app.js:1366
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:785
fn @ app.js:151
1 @ app.js:1379
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:785
checkDeferredModules @ app.js:46
(anonymous) @ app.js:861
(anonymous) @ app.js:864
Show 11 more frames
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '#<Object>' in NaN
    at eval (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"aeb9565a-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/MissionPlanner.vue?vue&type=template&id=e2c8c042&scoped=true& (app.js:946), <anonymous>:21:20)
    at Proxy.renderList (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2630)
    at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"aeb9565a-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/MissionPlanner.vue?vue&type=template&id=e2c8c042&scoped=true& (app.js:946), <anonymous>:19:15)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3548)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4468)
    at mountComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4073)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8415)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118)
```

The first error says something about 'reactive properties'. I am not sure what these errors mean. Here is my MissionPlanner.vue template & script

```
<template>
  <div>
   
    <h1 id="jl">Justice League Mission Planner</h1>

    <ul class="roster">
      <h3>Roster:</h3>
      <li v-for="hero in heroes"
          :key="hero.name">

        <span v-if="hero in chosen-heroes.chosenHeroes">✔ &nbsp;</span>

        <span>{{ hero.name }}&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="edit"
              @click="editHero(hero)">edit</span>
      </li>
      <br>
      <input type="text"
             placeholder="new name"
             v-model="newName"
             v-if="isEdit"
             @keyup.enter="changeName"
             @blur="clear">
      <br>
      <span v-if="isEdit">enter to submit, click outside the box to cancel</span>
    </ul>
    <chosen-heroes :heroes="heroes" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChosenHeroes from "./components/ChosenHeroes.vue";

export default {
  components: {
   "chosen-heroes" : ChosenHeroes
  },
  data() {
    return {
      heroes: [
        { name: "Superman" },
        { name: "Batman" },
        { name: "Aquaman" },
        { name: "Wonder Woman" },
        { name: "Green Lantern" },
        { name: "Martian Manhunter" },
        { name: "Flash" }
      ],
      newName: "",
      isEdit: false,
      heroToModify: null
    };
...
</script>
```

Comment: You have a typo: `comonents` should be `components`.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: Did you tried it with closing tags? `<mission-planner></mission-planner>`

Comment: @palasH yes i got some errors upon closer inspection. I am not sure what they mean though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span v-if="hero in chosen-heroes.chosenHeroes">✔ &nbsp;</span>
```

Here is the *chosen* referenced during render but not defined on the instance.
I guess you want to check if this particular hero is part of this list

```
data() {
return {
  heroes: [
    { name: "Superman" },
    { name: "Batman" },
    { name: "Aquaman" },
    { name: "Wonder Woman" },
    { name: "Green Lantern" },
    { name: "Martian Manhunter" },
    { name: "Flash" }
  ],
  newName: "",
  isEdit: false,
  heroToModify: null
}
```

You can write any javascript expression in the v-if so you can try:

```
<span v-if="heroes.map(heroObject => heroObject.name).includes(hero.name)">✔ &nbsp;</span>
```

I used the Array.map() function here so you can keep your list with objects. You could remove it if you write directly the names in the array.

**EDIT:**
The best would probably be to use a computed property here to make it more reusable and take this long expression out of the v-if:

```
isInList(heroName) {
  return this.heroes.map(heroObject => heroObject.name).includes(heroName);
}
```

then

```
<span v-if="isInList(hero.name)">✔ &nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: i want to say - if the hero is in the list of heroes, then render a checkbox by their name

Comment: sorry I actually wanted to say 
If the hero is in the list of ChosenHeroes then render the checkbox by their name
ChosenHeroes is like a child component which returns an array of ChosenHeroes in it